# Page with the authRequired meta still gets shown for a split second even when no one is logged in on Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication, vue-router

I'm new to Vue / web development, ever since I started i've had a good amount of fun but now i'm stuck.

Currently I am creating an admin dashboard with Firebase authentication. Everything seems to work like it should but there is one thing that I still don't understand.

In the Vue Router I have all the different routes set up and the dashboard is inaccessible (if not logged in to Firebase).

This is my Router Guard:

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Home",
    component: Home,
  },
  {
    path: "/register",
    name: "Register",
    component: Register,
  },
  {
    path: "/login",
    name: "Login",
    component: Login,
  },
  {
    path: "/dashboard",
    name: "Dashboard",
    component: Dashboard,
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: true,
    },
  },
];       

 router.beforeEach((to) => {
      //If route requires authentication
      if (to.matched.some((rec) => rec.meta.requiresAuth)) {
        //Check firebase user
        auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
          console.log(user);
          //If the user object does not exist then redirect to the /Login page
          if (!user) {
            router.push("/login");
          }
        });
      }
    });
```

If I now try to open localhost:8080/dashboard it shows the dashboard for a split second and then hops to the /login page.

If also tried it with `next({name: 'Login'})` but for some reason I keep getting white pages when I use next().

Hope someone can help me.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that instead of checking for a logged-in user you are adding an "event listener" `auth.onAuthStateChanged`.. it fires async when the authentication state changes. However you need a sync check here. The best would be to use vuex and store your user in a global state. Though if you don't use vuex at all and you need your user only here, then probably a "local" user var in the router would also work.. something like this:

```
let user = null
auth.onAuthStateChanged(u => {
   console.log(u)
   if (u) {
     user = u
   } else {
     user = null
   }
})

router.beforeEach(to => {
  if (to.matched.some(rec => rec.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    //Check firebase user
    if (!user) {
      router.push("/login");
    }
  }
})
```

It's just a concept, but it should work.. let me know :)

Comment: I just now noticed that I never responded to your solution but this was in fact the right solution. In the end, I made use of vuex-persistedstate since a refresh also deleted the user data. Thank you very much :)